# 18.04 to Lubuntu back to 18.04 - Computer not getting passed the start-up loading page

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, startup

My computer is a bit old and has 4GB RAM. I wanted to switch to lubuntu since I heard it's better with memory. During the installation I had second thoughts and crtl-Z'd the terminal and ended the lubuntu installation. But it was loading for a couple minutes in the meantime. I went to start my computer the next day and lubuntu start screen showed up but then switched to 18.04 after logging in.

I ran the command listed here under lubuntu:

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu

and then did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to make sure all the files for 18.04 were still intact. One of the files I notice being deleted by the psychocat command was ubuntu-desktop. After seeing ubuntu was not getting passed the loading page, I ran the install for ubuntu-desktop from the command line and ran upgrade and update once more but it's still getting not getting passed the ubunutu load page. I should also add that the load page is the 18.04 load page and when logging in by the terminal it also states Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on the top left.

There are of course many posts like mine about this problem. All of the solutions I have tried and all of the responses to the problem have to deal with lightdm or a nvidia drive. Since ubuntu before the lubuntu was running fine, there isn't anything wrong with my video card and on top of that I already tried all of the commands with lightdm.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand sorry.  Do you mean you were using Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME) and tried adding the `lubuntu-desktop` package, which was what you ^Z aborted?     The graphic screen you describe as a 'start screen' was probably a `plymouth` graphic used to hide [text boot] messages (users don't seem to like) & is unimportant and unrelated to the OS (it's just a graphic picture)  You may have been unable to login as your $HOME (user directory) is full & gui logins will fail until you create some space. But i'm unsure exactly your issue.  Check disk space & `sudo apt -f install`...

Comment: At the greeter screen, you can select which desktop you want to login using the gear logo (lxde or gnome - gnome being the default for Ubuntu 18.04, LXDE the default for Lubuntu 18.04).  The greeter (display manager whether lightdm, gdm3 or the alternatives) just operate slightly differently, some with more functions than others but using more resources.   The background image is just like a wallpaper, and can be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

on the terminal and instead of using lightdm I switched it to gdm3. Restarted and worked. I do notice upon start up that it STILL tries to switch to lubuntu (the screen turns from a black red to a black blue color -- 18.04 is black red and black blue is lubuntu) so I do believe there is still a problem but at least it loads up and functions again. If anyone has any idea there, I'd appreciate some feedback.